# In the Wordpress admin, how can I find out which page (themes.php, widgets.php, etc.) I'm on?

Tags: wp-admin

In the Wordpress admin, how can I programmatically find out which page (`themes.php`, `widgets.php`, etc.) I'm on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine that with wordpress' [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function. It will not return just a page name though, it will give you an object containing a bunch of different data on what screen you're on.

Comment: For a properly formatted output of that function, use this code chunk - `<pre><?php print_r(get_current_screen()); ?></pre>` - it makes for a nice nested list, I use it whenever I need to echo any object or array-based variable.

Comment: Weird... `get_current_screen()` is reported as undefined. Do I have to declare a global variable into scope, or anything else?

Comment: How are you calling it up?

Comment: I was calling it up in a theme's functions.php file, so I guess that's too early. I will try and add that to a later action.

Comment: Which action do you hook it to? I tried hooking it up to `admin_init`, but apparently `global $current_screen;` is still unset at that point.

Comment: I would probably use `admin_head` myself, but look here - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/function-get_current_screen-can-it-use-by-themesfunctionsphp?replies=3 - to see an example that's working.  Maybe you can take it from there?

Comment: You can also use `admin_menu`, but `_admin_menu` is too early and `adminmenu` too late. :)

Comment: I meant `admin_head` works. For some reason, `admin_menu` does not seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request , which shows a `current_screen` hook which is perfect to use for this sort of debugging (it also explains why `admin_head` works but `admin_menu` doesn't, since the `current_screen` hook runs *after* `admin_head`).